# comprise or comprise of

Tags: grammar

I have found a similar topic addressing the use of "comprise" but my question is not exactly in line with that one. I  did ask this question there to keep the topic related to the use of "comprise" but it was removed since I did not follow protocol. So my apologies if this seems like a duplicate entry.

When does one use "comprises of" and when "comprise"? Are they interchangeable?

For example:

"My name comprises 5 letters"

"My name comprises of 5 letters"

Which is correct? Or are they both acceptable?

Comment: This much I know, but other sources I have found indicate an increased usage of "of" in recent years, showing acceptance of the word. Have a look at the discussion labelled "Compose and Comprise"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A quick look in a decent online dictionary is advisable:

> **comprise** Usage: The use of *of* after comprise should be avoided:
>
> the library comprises (not comprises of) 500 000 books and manuscripts
>   Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged Collins.

I don't think US usage is any different.

Another quote, from the internet (repunctuated):

> Never use 'comprise of' or 'comprises of' - but 'comprised of' *is*
>   allowed.

This is a passive (or arguably adjectival) usage involving comprised which some consider to be ungrammatical (see http://grammarsource.com/2007/03/26/comprised-v-is-comprised-of/ ) .

Answer (score 8):

I support Mr Edwin Ashworth. When used in the active voice, COMPRISE is not followed by OF but when used in the passive voice, it is followed by OF:
The programme comprises two short plays.
The programme is comprised of two short plays.