# A semi-colon before a "comprised of" list, or a new sentence?

Tags: punctuation, lists, semicolons, colons

I'm writing something along the lines of

> The service is comprised of two parts; detailed tracking, and logging.

Should I employ the semi-colon, as above, or is a colon more appropriate? Or should I start a new sentence? My feeling, because this is such a short list, is that a new sentence would be somewhat clunky. This is a follow up to the helpful answer I found about **[comprise](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107869/comprise-or-comprise-of)**.

Comment: IMO a colon is definitely the better choice.  A colon indicates clearly that the clarification or exposition of the first part, comes in the second part.  A semicolon however merely indicates somehow-related ideas being merged into a single sentence.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. The direct indication, offered by the colon, is something that had escaped me.

Answer (score -1):

1. "Comprised of" is non-standard usage; "composed of" is preferred.
2. When introducing a list with a colon, it's common to separate the subsequent list items with a semicolon *or* to format the list items as bulleted phrases (though this is far less common).

The service is composed of two parts: detailed tracking; and logging.

*alternatively—though much less common:*

The service is composed of two parts:

- detailed tracking.
- logging.

Comment: _"composed of" is preferred_ by whom?

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/composed?q=composed

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/can-you-use-comprised-of-grammar

Comment: But your first linked reference gives 'is comprised of' in a sentence.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Giraffedata/comprised_of

Comment: https://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2015/01/comprised-of-vs-composed-of-a-test.html

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/news-trend-watch/comprise-2015-02-05

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/news-trend-watch/comprise-2015-02-05

Answer (score -2):

Semicolons are used to separate two independent clauses without conjunction, which isn’t the case for your sentence, so you should use a comma. Also, looking up the word [*comprise*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/comprise) in Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English, the example it shows is almost like yours:

> The house comprises two bedrooms, a kitchen, and a living room.

Comment: Why downvote, if you don’t mind taking a minute to explain the issue rather than clicking a button?

Comment: I'd love to know that too. I didn't down vote it.

Comment: Hi @Dave. Maybe consider upvoting if you found the answer helpful:)

Comment: Your sentence is NOT "almost like" Op's sentence: your sentence has a verb ("comprises") *introducing a **list***. In Op's sentence the verbal phrase ("is comprised of") introduces the *phrase* "of two parts" - and **the sentence could end there**: "The service is comprised of two parts." In Op's sentence, the list is *an expansion / explanation* of the words "two parts"; but your sentence **does not have** anything corresponding to the words "two parts". Therefore, Op's sentence needs punctuation to connect the words "two parts" with the list that amplifies those "two parts". ... Cont'd

Comment: Cont'd ... In my view that 'connection' between "... two parts" and the following list of those two parts requires either a colon (:) or an em-dash. The list after the colon or dash **amplifies** the words "two parts".  Your sentence has nothing equivalent to the words "two parts" in Op's sentence.

Comment: As someone who has not voted on this answer, but often explains his downvotes to other answers, may I answer your comment “Why downvote if you don’t mind talking a minute …”. My experience is that frequently this results in an aggressive and abusive response from the person who has made the answer. As a comment is not required for a downvote, I suspect many list members prefer to avoid the “agro”.